# Atmosphere low level protocol with Android

Tags: android, comet, atmosphere

Is it possible to use Atmosphere with android? (No WebView) Does a specific library (that manages unreliability in mobile connections) exist? Where could I find any documentation about it?

Comment: Did jwebsocket work with atmosphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a library for android that implements WebSocket protocol. I think it could be usable with atmosphere in websockets environment. The library is

http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/tutorial/pubsub.html

I have also found this:
http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocket

The second one seems to have more features. The comparison is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations